# RSS dashboard widget not showing visuals

Tags: widgets, rss, dashboard

I am using a RSS feeds widget on my dashboard as [shown in this Q&A](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/91027/different-rss-feeds-in-a-single-dashboard-widget/91031?noredirect=1#comment123299_91031). Problem is feeds doesn't show up any visual like images or videos. I verified this by looking raw feeds which I used. Here is a snapshot of my feed dashboard widget:
[image].

How can I get visuals or is this the way WordPress shows data?

Comment: Taylor, try to research this site for building a Question, this way the answerer only spends time on the solution and not in the research. As you can see, I built the Answer with bits already existent here in [wordpress.se] ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't manage to make `wp_widget_rss_output` to show the content without stripping HTML tags. Reference Q&A's:

- [WordPress SimplePie modifications](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/87359/12615)
- [Displaying images from external RSS feeds?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/2982/12615)

But, using the function [**`fetch_feed`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed) we can grab the full feed contents. Check also the [**SimplePie**](http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/start#simplepie_item) function reference. See comments for details:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: RSS Dashboard Widget with Images
 * Version: 1.0
 * Description: Display an array of feeds in a dashboard widgets displaying full content without stripping any HTML tags
 * Author: Rodolfo Buaiz
 * Author URI: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/12615/brasofilo
 * Plugin URI: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/91137/12615
 *
 * License: GPLv2 or later
 */

add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'multiple_feeds_wpse_91137' );

function multiple_feeds_wpse_91137() 
{
     wp_add_dashboard_widget( 
        'dashboard_custom_feed', 
        'Latest News', 
        'dashboard_feed_output_wpse_91137' 
    );
}

function dashboard_feed_output_wpse_91137() 
{
    // Array with Title => Address
    $feeds = array( 
        'CBC Canada'     => 'http://rss.cbc.ca/lineup/topstories.xml',
        'Valencia Spain' => 'feed://www.levante-emv.com/elementosInt/rss/39', 
        'WP Engineer'    => 'http://wpengineer.com/feed/',
    );

    // Set max-height and enable scrolling
    echo '<div class="rss-widget" style="max-height:300px;overflow-y:auto">';

    // Iterate through feed
    foreach( $feeds as $title => $url )
    {
        echo "<h3>$title</h3>";

        // Fetch feed
        $rss = fetch_feed( $url );

        // Check for errors
        if ( is_wp_error( $rss ) )
        {
            echo "error fetching: $title";
        }
        else
        {
            // Process feed items using SimplePie methods
            $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity(4);
            $rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, $maxitems); 

            // Nothing in the feed
            if ($maxitems == 0) 
            {
                echo 'No items.';
            } 
            // Iterate through feed items
            else 
            {
                echo '<ul>';
                foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) 
                { 
                    // Prepare contents
                    $link = $item->get_permalink();
                    $title = $item->get_title();
                    $date = $item->get_date();
                    $content = $item->get_content();
                    // Display content
                    echo "<li><a href='$link'>$title</a> : <small>$date</small><br />$content</li>"; 
                }
                echo '</ul>';
            }
        }       
    }
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Reference Q&A's:

- [placement of wp_error with fetch_feed](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/13155/12615)
- [Combining RSS Feeds and Sorting with fetch_feed](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73539/12615)
- [wp_remote_get vs. fetch_feed ? which is the better for performance?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/71277/12615)

Comment: learnt alot,, especially from these references you provided. Thanks Braso!
Code works smoothly,I have heard about simple pie and also about yahoo pipes, but never intended to use. Now I will modify further using these.

Comment: Well, I learned a lot too with this one, ain't this place cool?! ;)